# Using a for loop to write into cells in an Excel file, removes the previous column

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm trying to write a code that finds a certain column in an input Excel file and reorganizes it in an output excel file. I've gotten the for loop completed and it works. However, when I try to set up a similar for loop for the next condition it removes the column it had written before in the previous if statement. I can't seem to figure out why this occurs.
I had the program print what cellnum, j, i, and data were and it seems that it knows where it should write the data, but it still only prints one column of data in the output file.

```
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.SheetConditionalFormatting;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.ConditionalFormattingRule;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.ComparisonOperator;//compare two different values
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.PatternFormatting;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.IndexedColors;


import java.util.Iterator;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

public class Reorganizer 
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    /*File Chooser*/
    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();//lets user choose file
    int returnValue = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);//null bc we don't have parent classes, lets user choose through an open window

    if(returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
    {
        try 
        {
            Workbook wb= new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(fileChooser.getSelectedFile()));//setting the input file as a workbook
            Sheet inputSheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);//the sheet from the input file

            Workbook wb1 = new HSSFWorkbook();//creating a new workbook to later be put into the output file
            Sheet outputSheet = wb1.createSheet("Sheet 1");//creates new sheet on the output excel file


        //first need something to find cell# of the file
            Row idRow = inputSheet.getRow(0);
            int cellCounter=0;
            for(Iterator<Cell> cit = idRow.cellIterator(); cit.hasNext();)//goes down the row, until there is nothing
            {                   
                Cell cell = cit.next();
                cellCounter++;
            }
            //finds the number of rows
            int rowCounter=0;
            for(Iterator<Row> rit = inputSheet.rowIterator();rit.hasNext();)//goes down the column, until there is nothing
            {                   
                Row row = rit.next();
                rowCounter++;
            }


            //The first row of the document should be the labeling process
            //Set the row(0) and the cells(9)
            Row labelRow = outputSheet.createRow(0);
            //for loop to make 9 cells with labels
            String[] cellValues = new String[]{"Chr","Pos","OR","Subfamily","Cluster","OP6u","OP6d","OP27u","OP27d"};
            for(int i=0; i<=9;i++)
            {
                Cell labelCells = labelRow.createCell(i);
                if(i<=8)
                {
                     labelCells.setCellValue(cellValues[i]);
                     for(Iterator<Cell> cit = idRow.cellIterator(); cit.hasNext(); )
                        {
                            Cell cell = cit.next();
                            cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                            if(cellValues[i].equals(cell.getStringCellValue()))
                            {
                                for(int j=1;j<rowCounter;j++)
                                {
                                    int cellnum = cell.getColumnIndex();
                                    Cell inputCell = inputSheet.getRow(j).getCell(cellnum);
                                    inputCell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                                    String data = inputCell.getStringCellValue();
                                    Cell outputCell = outputSheet.createRow(j).createCell(i);
                                    outputCell.setCellValue(data);
System.out.println(cellnum);
                                    System.out.println(i);
                                    System.out.println(j);
                                    System.out.println(data);


                                }
                            }
                        }
                } 
                else 
                {
                     labelCells.setCellValue("");
                }

            }
        FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("Reorganized.xls");
        wb1.write(output);
        output.flush();
        output.close();
        }

        catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

}
```

}

Comment: Can you post the full code?

Comment: Added the entire code

Answer (score 0):

Without compiling the code, there looks like there may be a bug when you are writing to your FileOutputStream output. try running flush() before closing the stream.

Your code is doing this:

```
FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("ChrTestExcel.xls");
wb1.write(output);
output.close();
```

Try this instead:

```
FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("ChrTestExcel.xls");
wb1.write(output);
output.flush();
output.close();
```

After walking the code, there seem to be some cleaning up that needs to be done. First, you could be a little more concise with your code. The first loop can be be shortened like so:

Existing for Loop

```
for(int i=0; i<=9;i++)
        {
            Cell labelCells = labelRow.createCell(i);
            //if statements that make the labels
            if(i==0)
            {
                labelCells.setCellValue("Chr");
            }
            else if(i==1)
            {
     ...
```

Suggested refactoring for conciseness

```
String[] cellValues = new String[]{"Chr","Pos","OR","Subfamily","Cluster","OP6u","OP6d","OP27u","OP27d"};
for(int i=0; i<=9;i++){
    Cell labelCells = labelRow.createCell(i);
    if(i<=8){
         labelCells.setCellValue(cellValues[i]);
    } else {
         labelCells.setCellValue("");
    }
    //do something with the cell you just created! 
}
```

The second part is to actually do something with the Cells you are creating (See previous code example). Once that loop goes from i==0 to i==1, the value for labelCells is lost (scope error). Somehow you will have to increment the position of the cell, add it to a row, etc.

Comment: The problem isn't the this for loop, its the for loop later on that seems to be compiling strangely. If one for loop within the if statement exist then it runs fine. However if two for loops, that are responsible for writing data, in the loop exists it will only create the column that is of the later for loop. So when compiled only a single column of data appears. Thanks for the concise code btw!

Comment: The problem isn't how many for loops within if statements, but what is happening and when it is happening. I suggest you follow the flow in your code on paper or a whiteboard. Errors will become more apparent if you watch the changes in your code happen.

Comment: I did some major concision work and edited the code. I also had the program tell me what row and column it was adding the data. The printed data looked fine but when I open the Excel output file, only one column of data seems to be have written. I'll try going through it on paper though

Comment: Now you are on to something! Make sure you are adding any cells to the document and that you are creating as well as flushing any output streams on a regular basis. Good job, keep it up!

Comment: So after every completion of the for loop, how do I make sure the data I just put in stays in? Cause it seems that every time it goes through the for loop the previous data that was just written has been deleted.

Comment: Ensure that when you are done adding a column that you move to the next column before adding any more cells, same goes with rows.

Comment: It does, when I break after the first loop it inputs the correct data. I really don't understand why only a single column is formed